# Closing answered questions

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I'm quite new and sometimes look for unanswered questions. But in many of them I see that owner wrote in comment "I solved it, thanks" and didn't accept the answer (although it was correct and helped him) or users added answer in comment so he wrote in comment thank you.

Should there be (or is there) any option that other ordinary users can use to mark such a topic as answered so it is no longer be displayed as an unanswered question, or move comment as answer?

Comment: see [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: Basically, you can either convert the comments into a (community wiki?) answer so that there is an answer, or you can vote to close the question (it probably has no lasting benefit to the community).  The nearest approach to closing it might be the 'Off-topic - trivial typo' excuse.  It gets used for such questions as there isn't necessarily a better way to handle them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "answered".

- If the question was answered as a result of a conversation in comments, and no further details were added to the original post to potentially answer it without delving into comments, **or** it was answered by the OP with outstanding requests to clarify the actual problem in comments, then it's **Off Topic** because the post **lacked sufficient details** to answer it.
- If the question was answered by someone other than the OP, and it sufficiently answers the question and/or is useful, then **upvote it.**  Acceptance only really applies to the OP, and **it's up to them** if they accept the answer or not.
- If the question was answered by someone other than the OP, and it is actually wrong and/or not useful, then **downvote it.**

Comment: You forgot: If you don't see connection between the answer and the question, or the answer is just a lucky guess to a overly unclear question, close the whole thing ;)

Comment: Very good point.  I'll add that in when I'm on a machine next.